# how to add category sub menu in product page of website magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, products

I would like to add sub categories like "**categories** & **Shops**" on product listing page (as displayed in below image1). Further upon hovering on these sub menus, it should display the child menus (as shown in below image2).

[image: Image1:product sub categories]**
[image: Image2:child categories on hovering]

Answer (score 0):

I have write code for subcategory listing on product listing page you can add hover effect by follow this code.
[image]
Paste this code on `list.phtml`

```
<?php

$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentId = $currentCat->getId();
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

echo '<ul class="test">';
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
        {
         $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
            if($_category->getIsActive()) {

            echo '<li class="category-listing">';    ?>
              <div class="category-link"><a href=" <?php echo $_category->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName(); ?>"><h3><?php echo $_category->getName(); ?></h3></a></div>

              </li>
              <?php  }
        }
 echo '</ul>';

?>
```